# Mudar centavos de valores

Tags: javascript

Eu gostaria de conseguir mudar os centavos dos `li` pelo input de `MudarCentavos`. Mas não setando `Id` nos `li` e ir tratando `Id`por `Id`, porque essa lista será dinâmica, então podem vir mais do que 3 valores.

*Obs: 2 Casas decimais*

```js
function MudarCentavos() {
  var getCentavos = document.getElementById('getCentavos').value
  console.log(getCentavos)
}
```

```html
<label>Mudar centavos</label>
<input type="text" maxlength="2" pattern="([0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9])" id="getCentavos">
<button onclick="MudarCentavos()">Submit</button>

<ul>
  <li>24.50</li>
  <li>10.2</li>
  <li>43</li>
</ul>
```

**Exemplo**

Se eu colocar no input `99` e der o `Submit`, o output dos valores será:

```
  24.99
  10.99
  43.99
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Pode ser mais específico? em 'mudar os centavos dos p', aonde tem p? ao mudar você quer zerar todos os centavos e ir adicionando os novos? quer somente substituir pelo input ?

Comment: @Felipe Confundi a tag, é o `li`. não tem `p`... vou atualizar a pergunta com um exemplo de como gostaria  =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acho que você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   $('#mudarCentavos').click(function(){
       // Recebe o valor input
       var centavos = document.getElementById('getCentavos').value
 
       // Percorre todas as <li> da <ul> com o ID #valores
       $('#valores li').each(function( index, value ){
           var novo_valor = Math.trunc( parseFloat( $(value).text() ) ); // paseFloat vai converter o valor para o tipo float, já a função Math.trunc retorna somente a parte inteira de um número, ou seja, ela descarta as casas decimais.
           novo_valor = novo_valor + ( centavos / 100 ); // Soma o valor atual com os centavos informados no input
           $(value).html( novo_valor.toFixed(2) ); // a função toFizex converte um número em string mas mantendo a quantidade de casas decimais que você informar.
       });
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Mudar centavos</label>
<input type="text" maxlength="2" pattern="([0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9])" id="getCentavos">
<button id="mudarCentavos">Submit</button>

<ul id="valores">
   <li>24.50</li>
   <li>10.2</li>
   <li>43</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ele quer mudar os centavos e não somar

Comment: é verdade @LeoCaracciolo tinha entendido errado, mas já corrigir a função.

Comment: Excelente!! Muito obrigado!!! :)

Comment: explicar o que foi feito é sempre interessante

Comment: Eu entendi. Dei uma googlada no `Math.trunc()`, Mas algum outro pode não entender de primeira :)

Comment: Por nada @Jackson!

Answer (score 3):

Com javascript puro, fazendo uso do método [`Math.trunc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc)

> O método Math.trunc() retorna a parte inteira de um número, descartando suas casas decimais.

```js
function MudarCentavos() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("UL")[0].getElementsByTagName("LI");
    
     var centavos = document.getElementById('getCentavos').value
    
     var list = document.getElementsByTagName("UL")[0];
     
     for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        var novo_valor = Math.trunc( document.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].innerHTML );
        novo_valor = novo_valor + ( centavos / 100 );
     list.getElementsByTagName("LI")[i].innerHTML = novo_valor;
     }
}
```

```html
<label>Mudar centavos</label>
<input type="text" maxlength="2" pattern="([0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9])" id="getCentavos">
<button onclick="MudarCentavos()">Submit</button>

<ul>
  <li>24.50</li>
  <li>10.2</li>
  <li>43</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Só funcionou na primeira <ul>.

Comment: Show cara, obrigado!